# Very low IoU for semantic Segmentation on Pascal VOC data using DeeplabV3 model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train a model in TensorFlow for semantic segmentation on the Pascal VOC dataset and I am not able to attain more than a 0.3 IoU score on the validation set. My implementation is similar to https://github.com/rishizek/tensorflow-deeplab-v3. I have used a batch size of 10, with SGD and momentum=0.9, and running on GPU for distributed training but use a static learning rate of 0.003 without the batch normalization decay as suggested in the original deeplabv3 paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05587.pdf. Can anyone provide any suggestions of how this might be improved? I know the suggestions mentioned in the paper should help but even without them, they achieve around 0.6 mIoU

Comment: Are you using all the classes? Please use exactly the parameters as described in the paper and review the results and then try to modify other parameters. Try to run on a single GPU with a smaller batch size, so that we reduce all possible sources of error/problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you followed the original paper on DeepLabV3+? Some things that perhaps, you might have missed:

1. Have your backbone pre-trained with ImageNet.
2. Use SBD dataset not pure PASCAL for training. SBD is an expanded version of PASCAL.
   (http://home.bharathh.info/pubs/pdfs/BharathICCV2011.pdf).
   Almost never pure PASCAL VOC is used for training, always go with SBD and Always have data augmentation during training: expansion, cropping, etc. They do this in the deeplab work. Maybe you are doing this.. just good to check.
3. In the deeplab they used learning rate decay over 30k steps (note, not epochs). Check the DeepLabV3 paper, section "training protocol".
4. In my personal experience, the mean iou published are quite hard to replicate :/ there are so many small details that can be missed.
5. Always make sure you're calculating your iou properly...
6. In the deeplab they use 16 of batch size.
7. Which SGD exactly are you using? Did you try Adam with poly decay?
8. Which backbone did you choose? I think they used resnet and xception. I recommend Xception.

The paper you referenced is good, but the deeplab went through some evolutions:

- DeepLab:
  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7062.pdf
- DeepLabV2:
  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00915.pdf
- DeepLabV3: (you mentioned this one)
  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.05587.pdf
- DeepLabV3+:
  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02611v3.pdf

I recommend going to the latest one. They made improvements and it's the easier to understand, I think.
If you are doing all of those it could be something else. A lot of implementations on the internet get the decoder of DeepLab wrong (in my opinion).